Ignore Properties That Are Inherited From Base Class
I've a base class User that's used by EF Core and here's the configuration for that as follows:
public class UserConfiguration: IEntityTypeConfiguration<User>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<User> builder)
    {
        builder.ToTable("Users");

        builder.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        builder.Property(x => x.Id).HasColumnName("UserId");
        builder.Property(x => x.FirstName).HasColumnName("FirstName");

        builder.Ignore(x => x.ClientVersion);
        builder.Ignore(x => x.LastUsedByClient);
    }
}

Base Class:
public class User
{
     public int Id { get; set; }    
     public string FirstName { get; set; }
     public string ClientVersion { get; set; }
     public string LastUsedByClient { get; set; }
}

Now I've a requirement to extend the class properties without changing anything in the configuration.
public class UserRequest : User
{
     public DateTime UpdateDate  { get; set; }
     public bool Status  { get; set; }
}

How can I ignore the properties that are in the new class inherited from the base class User? My plan is to use the new class as follows:
Context.Users.Add(UserRequest); //To add data in database with the user context


Not sure how you configured your entities, but as long as you keep entity type as User it will work correctly (as I just tested). Moreover, I would create rather DTO class to carry the data about the User.

My advice is you learn to test with code-first, and then try to write a few classes and see what database first gets build. With the code you wrote both User and UserRequest will save in same table and EF will use a column "UserType" to specify what class it serializes into. User class will break if the data isn't present.

I think that your model is wrong. A UserRequest should not inherit from User but have a relationship with User. I.e., a User should have a 1-to-n relationship to UserRequest.
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string ClientVersion { get; set; }
    public string LastUsedByClient { get; set; }

    // Navigation property to children
    public List<UserRequest> UserRequests { get; set; }
}

public class UserRequest
{
    public int Id { get; set; } // Add this PK to UserRequest

    public DateTime UpdateDate  { get; set; }
    public bool Status  { get; set; }

    // Navigation properties to parent
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public User User { get; set; }
}

Generally we can say that an inheriting class is a of the type of its parent class as well. Example:
public class User { ... }
public class SuperUser : User
{ 
    public void DeleteUser(User user) 
    {
        ...
    }
}

Here SuperUser inherits from User. The SuperUser is a User, but with additional privileges.
var super = new SuperUser();
if (super is User) {
    // Always true, if-statement is obsolete.
}

User selectedUser = ...;
User user = ...;
if (user is SuperUser superUser) {
    // Executes only if user is a SuperUser
    superUser.DeleteUser(selectedUser);
}

But a UserRequest is not a User!
See also:

Introduction to relationships - EF Core | Microsoft Learn


I think, this looks great. Will try it.

first I would recommend you to read more about Inheritance Mapping Strategies in .net you can find on this here
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Entity<User>()
        .ToTable("Users");
        
    modelBuilder.Entity<UserRequest>()
        .ToTable("UserRequests")
        .HasBaseType<User>();

    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
}

this will create table per type we have two different tables in the database don't forget to run migration and update the database ,
then you can create the same fluent validation on the UserRequest Type ,
I don't know if you are really need to create inheritance relation ship in my opinion it's enough to add the both properties inside the User Class
let me know if you'r still confused I ill explain more to you , hope this works with you
